# Which of the following vectors are in span[v1, v2, v3]?

Tags: linear-algebra

"Suppose we have $v_1=(2,1,3,0), v_2=(3,-1,2,5) v_3=(-1,0,1,2)$. Which of the following vectors are in $span\{v1,v2,v3\}$?"

$a) (9,0,11,12);$

$b) (2,2,2,2)$

So, from what I know the determinant has to be non-zero for the vector to span. 
According to the answer key, $(9,0,11,12) \in span\{v1,v2,v3\}$, and $(2,2,2,2) \notin span\{v1,v2,v3\}$.

I have calculated the determinant of both $a$ and $b$ by putting up an augmented matrix and reducing the the first column to zeros except from the first entry in row $1$, followed by co-factor expansion or calculating the diagonal product. From a i get a non-zero determinant but I also get that from $b$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve
$$\pmatrix{2&3&-1\\1&-1&0\\3&2&1\\0&5&2}\pmatrix{c_1\\c_2\\c_3}=b_i$$
with $b_1=\pmatrix{9\\0\\11\\12}$ and $b_2=\pmatrix{2\\2\\2\\2\\}$.

The one that has a solution, guess only one, is your solution.

Comment: Solve by gaussian elimination to RREF?

Comment: any method you familiar with will work.

Comment: okay, i think i have solved it now, a). result is consistent with fourth row only containing zeros and b). is inconsistent. thank you for the help Michael!